# No autowiring of BindingsEndpoint anymore when upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.0 from 2.7.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am upgrading a **Spring Cloud Stream** application from **Spring Boot 2.7.6 to 3.0.0**
So far, I had to change only some code to get the project compiled

- `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` to `KafkaHeaders.KEY`
- `KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord()` needs now a Duration as the 3rd parameter instead of long

But when starting the application the autowiring of `org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint` doesn't work anymore:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Is there a documentation, what has to be done, to get it working?**

Here is my [sample project](https://github.com/giraone/scs-resume/tree/spring-boot-3). The main branch contains the working code with Spring Boot 2.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spring-boot-3 branch, I see [this](https://github.com/giraone/scs-resume/blob/spring-boot-3/pom.xml#L19) where you set Spring Cloud Stream to `3.2.6`. You need to use a compatible `4.0.x` version. Update that to `4.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (or any `4.0.0` release), and the bindings endpoint should be available. I just verified that on my end with that change.